# How to create custom picklist from OpportunityStage for custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex

How to create custom picklist from OpportunityStage for custom object. I have custom object, need to create a picklist same as OpportunityStage or can i use OpportunityStage as picklist in any other object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule you can't reuse the picklist definition across objects. Simply make your own picklist and add the values to it.

There are few special picklists that work like that but Opportunity Stage isn't one of them:

- all Currency code picklists are managed in 1 central location (this is visible only if you have enabled the currency management)
- Lead -> Lead Source, Account -> Account Source and Contact -> Lead Source seem to be synchronized?